# Save programs settings in MonoProject

Tags: unix, app-config, monodevelop

I'm just start using UNIX System and MonoDevelop. In my MonoProject I want to get opportunity that user can save some parameters(login, password, URL and other). I using configuration file for it with next code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


    <appSettings>

        <add key="Login" value="MyLogin" />
        <add key="Password" value="MyPassword" />
        <add key="URL" value="MyURL" />            
    </appSettings>


</configuration>
```

Now I want to get Login from this file and wrote next code:

```
string param = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get ("Login");
```

But this code return NULL. Could you help me please, where I am wrong, how can I get parameters from config file? Could you show me some examples? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
string param = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login"];
```

Conifguration file looks pretty good.